# Convert or parse string to decimal

Tags: c#, string, parsing, format, decimal

I have this string: "7.0000000000000007E-2" (data.InnerText). I use the following code but this gave me the error: "Input string was not in a correct format.".

```
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(data.InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I only need the number rounded on 2 decimals.

Comment: It might help to tag this with language.

Comment: This is C#, I suppose, changed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

If your culture uses . as the decimal separator :

```
double d = double.Parse("7.0000000000000007E-02");
```

Or try that way :

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("7.0000000000000007E-02", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```